# Reference external javascript library in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was any way to reference an external JavaScript library within the JavaScript code itself.  This is the way I am normally doing it in html:

```
<script src="library link"></script>
```

but I was wondering if it was at all possible do an equivenlent thing in JavaScript code.

Comment: So, you want to load external libraries into your HTML, using only JS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: `var a = document.createElement('script'); a.src="..."; document.getElementsByTagName('head').appendChild(a);`